# How could I make a list look like a table, that automatically extends when info is added?

Tags: html, extend

I know how to make it look like a table, and I know how it would grow when info is added, but the problem is the table's border is rounded and has a header area to it. I was thinking of making it a background image but I don't know how I could get it to grow while keeping the rounded corners..

Image link:
http://i51.tinypic.com/15yyhe0.jpg

Any ideas would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

To make it grow you have to set the rounded corners as separate backgrounds. In html 5 this is a lot easier, however for the current usage you can check out [here](http://www.neuroticweb.com/recursos/css-rounded-box/)

This is an old site, that still works. This can also be done with javascript that doesn't use any images, there are lots of options depending on your end goal.

Are you wanting to grow width or height? Adding columns or rows? Are you going to use `<table>` or `<div>` tags?

Or are thinking of using accordions that expand upon user click [JS Accordions](http://www.p51labs.com/accordion/)

Comment: height is what I would like to grow, and rows will be added. I have to use <li> to create this table instead of <table>

Comment: If you separate the image into three pieces, top, bottom, and sides. Set these as background images for three different <div> tags that line up as appropriate for top, bottom, and sides. For the sides set the background to repeat-y (and it only need be a small piece of the side height wise but full width), then every time you add a row it will repeat the background. Does that make sense?